# How to create Group Membership in TFS?

Tags: tfs, group-membership

I want to create a group membership with below Template **for created** team project (not for new one):

```
<group name="Active" description="Active">
          <permissions>
            <permission name="GENERIC_READ" class="PROJECT" allow="true" />
            <permission name="DELETE_TEST_RESULTS" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
            <permission name="PUBLISH_TEST_RESULTS" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
            <permission name="VIEW_TEST_RESULTS" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
            <permission name="GENERIC_READ" class="CSS_NODE" allow="true" />
            <permission name="WORK_ITEM_READ" class="CSS_NODE" allow="true" />
            <permission name="WORK_ITEM_WRITE" class="CSS_NODE" allow="true" />
            <permission name="MANAGE_TEST_PLANS" class="CSS_NODE" allow="true" />
            <permission name="MANAGE_TEST_ENVIRONMENTS" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
            <permission name="MANAGE_TEST_CONFIGURATIONS" class="PROJECT" allow="false" />
          </permissions>
        </group>
```

note that in the existing wizard for creating new group membership(Context Menu>Team Project Settings>Group Membership), I **can not** set **WORK_ITEM_WRITE** and **WORK_ITEM_READ** permission!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XML, it says `class="CSS_NODE"`. This means that `WORK_ITEM_WRITE` and `WORK_ITEM_READ` permissions are set for each Area in a Team Project, rather than the Team Project itself.

Area-level permissions are specific to a single project's users and groups. You can set these permissions by **right-clicking the project in Team Explorer, clicking Areas and Iterations, and on the Area tab, clicking Security**.

See 'Area-level permissions' on the [Team Foundation Server Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx) page on MSDN.